# jQuery AJAX file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass an array of files in the ajax request here is my code :

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_edit_discussion', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var channel_id = $('#channel_id').val();
    var discussion_id = $('#discussion_id').val();
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var content = $('#content').val();
    var image_choice = [''];
    var image = [''];
    var new_image = [''];
    for (var i = 0; i < $('.images').data('images-count'); i++) {
        image_choice[i] = $('input[name="image_choice_' + i + '"]:checked').val();
        image[i] = $('#image_' + i).data('image-id');
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#images_i').val(); i++) {
        var j = i + 1;
        new_image[i] = $('#new_image_' + j + '').prop('files')[0];
    }
    $.post('edit', {
        'content': content,
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'channel_id': channel_id,
        'title': title,
        'discussion_id': discussion_id,
        'image': image,
        'image_choice': image_choice,
        'new_image': new_image
    }, function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The array new_image contains the images when i log it, it shows correctly but when i add it to the object data of the post request it wont work

Answer (score 0):

To upload files you need to send a `FormData` object that contains the binary data. You cannot serialise the files to strings - which is what your current code is attempting to do.

Note that you can massively simplify the process by using the constructor of `FormData` which accepts a `form` Element. You can achieve this by hooking to the `submit` event of the `form` instead of the `click` of the `submit` button. If all the values are not contained within `input` elements within the form then you can use the `append()` method to add them manually.

The data will then be populated in the FormData object with the keys of the `input` elements. Note that data in this method cannot be provided in arrays; each single value must have it's own key. You can serialise/deserialise data if you prefer to store it in a single key, but this will need to be done manually on the client and server respectively.

Here's a basic working example:

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#yourForm', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'edit',
    type: 'post',
    data: new FormData(this),
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: it wont work with me cause from the beginning $.ajax() function don't work with me so i use $.post() and $.get() functions

Comment: You need to investigate why `$.ajax()` doesn't work for you, as there is no reason that it shouldn't